# Vscode not displaying Emmet suggestion first

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

When typing a property short hand on CSS for some reason I get all these other options for every single property in css with those letters, but I just want the one from Emmet.

[image]

If at least it would remmeber the last selected one, I could live with that but even If I always select for example `margin-bottom` when typing `mb`, but it will not offer that one first.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of having the recently used one, which works for me is to add this to `settings.json`

```
"editor.suggestSelection": "recentlyUsedByPrefix"
```

Mind you, this did not work

```
"editor.suggestSelection": "recentlyUsed",
```